# How is lazy deletion advantageous/disadvantageous to a binary tree or linked list?

Tags: arrays, linked-list, binary-tree

Recently, for a data structures class, I was asked the question of how a lazy deletion (that is, a deletion that first marks the items needed to be deleted, and then at some time later deletes all the marked items) would be advantageous/disadvantageous to an array, linked list, or binary tree. Here is what I have come up with:

- This would help arrays because you would save the time that is taken to shift the array every time an index is deleted although in algorithms that need to traverse the array, there could be inefficiencies.
- This would not help linked lists because you need to traverse O(n) to mark an item to be deleted anyways.
- I'm not entirely sure about binary trees, but if it were a linked list implementation of one I would imagine it is like the linked list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it all depends on the circumstances and the requirements.  In a general sense using this method where they are marked and then deleted later they all have a lot of similar pros and cons.

Similar pros:
-When marked for deletion there is no shifting of the data structures, which makes deletion much faster.
-You can insert on top of a deleted item, which means no shifting for inserts either, plus insertion can be done faster since it can write over the first delete instead of looking for the end of a list

Similar cons:
-Waste of space for deleted item, since they are just sitting there
-Have to transverse twice to delete an item, once to mark it and once again to delete it
-Many marked items for deletion will pollute the data structure making searches take longer since deleted items have to be searched over.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to think a little deeper on the implementation of linked lists.  You indicate that lazy deletion would NOT help in any way because the time to search is all the time that is necessary to perform the delete.

Think about what it takes to actually REMOVE an item from a linked list.
note: this assumes a SINGLY linked list (not a double linked list)
1) Find the item to delete (because this is a SINGLE linked list, you always have to search, because you need the PREV item)
2) Keep pointers to the PREV and NEXT elements
3) Fix the "PREV" element to point to the NEXT element - thus, isolating the CURRENT element
3.5) in a double linked list, you also have to take care of the NEXT element pointing back to the PREV element.
4) Release the memory associated with CURRENT element

Now, what is the process for a lazy delete? --- much shorter
1) Find the item to delete (you may not even have to perform a search, as you already have a pointer to the object you want deleted?)
2) mark the item for deletion.

*) Wait for "Garbage collection" thread to run and actually perform the remaining steps WHEN the system is "IDLE"

A binary tree implemented as a linked list where each element has a left and a right - however, you still perform the same steps in the search.  Binary tree searching is just more efficient with O(Log(n)) I believe.

However, deleting from these becomes more complex because you have more pointers to deal with (both a "LEFT" and a "RIGHT") - so will take more instructions to fix, especially when you are deleting a tree node that has pointers to nodes for both the left and right -- one of them will need to be promoted to the new root - however, what if they also both already have their left and right pointers assigned? where does the original "left/right" node go? - You have to re-balance the tree at this point.  Thus, there is significant savings by mark for delete from a user perspective and having an "idle" garbage collection taking care of the memory details (so the user doesn't have to wait for that).

Answer (score 0):

I would think the answer would be "it depends" for various reasons, but I think you're on the right track.

1) I agree with your answer about arrays, assuming that there is a requirement that there are no holes in your array.  If you are not required to shift the array around on every delete, then the proposed mark now, delete later approach wouldn't help at all.  Either way, you are dealing with O(n) vs. (2O(n) = O(n)) for the algorithm, which are equal. The real thing to think about is "does reordering all of the deletions at one time vs. reordering each of the deletions individually save you any time?"  Assuming m is the number of deletions, the number of times that each element after the first deletion in your array is reordered is O(m) for the delete immediately approach as compared to O(1) for the mark now, delete later approach.

2) I agree with your answer for linked lists.

3) As for Binary Tree, I suppose it would depend what kind it is.  If you are using a sorted, balanced binary tree, you'll have to consider the same question as in 1) above, but if not, your thoughts are correct, and it should behave exactly like a linked list.